# C# using statement more understanding

Tags: c#, using

Can someone help me to understand following code

```
public Font MyFont { get; set; }

void AssignFont()
{
    using (Font f = new Font("Shyam",2))
    {
        this.MyFont = f;
    }
}
```

Is it valid to assign a disposing object to `MyFont` property?

Comment: I have seen this work! Always wanted an explanation though.

Comment: How is the `MyFont` property actually used? Disposing an object which is still referenced is not only fine, it's the normal situation. If you didn't still have a reference to it, you wouldn't be able to dispose it! So, what _specifically_ occurs after this code executes that you think shouldn't work but which does?

Comment: thanks. I understood now..i should be calling Dispose on MyFont after it has been used. I will be disposing this property in Dispose method of my control. here is explanation from microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.dispose.aspx

Comment: Ideally, we should not be having references to a disposed objects to allow GC to collect them. So is this usage of using wrong?

Comment: @bit: there's nothing wrong per se with retaining a reference to a disposed object. You should eliminate references to objects you won't use again, but this has nothing directly to do with whether the object implements `IDisposable`, nor whether the object has been disposed, except to the extent that _usually_ when you dispose an `IDisposable` object, that signals your intent that you are done using the object. What the OP is actually asking here, is not clear at all. Based on the most recent comment, it sounds like they are just not sure of _when_ to dispose an object.

Comment: Note: it seems to me that the original question has been mangled by the edits (admittedly in an understandable way). I believe the question being asked should read "Is it valid to assign an object that _will_ be disposed to the `MyFont` property?" I will wait for the OP to edit the question to clarify though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whilst it may be "valid to assign a disposed object to MyFont property", the object may no longer be useful because it may have released managed and/or unmanaged resources.  Objects that are instantiated in the opening of a `using` statement indicate that the object's underlying class realises the `IDisposable` interface.  This should be treated as a warning sign that when the object is *disposed* you should really stop interacting with it including keeping a reference to it.

In the case of a font, the font's underlying resources were disposed when you exited the using block:

```
using (Font f = new Font("Shyam",2))
{
    this.MyFont = f;
}
```

This is easily proven if you attempt to use the font in any drawing operation.

This code will fail with a `System.ArgumentException` because the font is disposed:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignMode)
        {
            return;
        }

        AssignFont();
    }

    #region Overrides of Control

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Control.Paint"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs"/> that contains the event data. </param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;

            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, e.ClipRectangle);

            g.DrawString("Hi there", MyFont, Brushes.Black, 0, 0); // <--- this will fail
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void AssignFont()
    {
        using (Font f = new Font("Shyam", 2))
        {
            this.MyFont = f;
        } // <---- MyFont now points to a disposed object
    }

    public Font MyFont { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

The problem with your code is that you are allocating something in a using block and keeping a reference to it elsewhere.  In your scenario because you want to use the font elsewhere it makes no sense to have a `using` block.

### Bad:

```
using (Font f = new Font("Shyam",2))
{
    this.MyFont = f;
}
```

### Better:

```
this.MyFont = new Font("Shyam",2)
```

Fonts I suspect make use of native fonts hence the resource.

Answer (score 4):

**General rule of thumb:** Don't use a disposable object outside the `using` block. Most of the time, disposable objects are unusable once disposed. If you follow this rule, you'll run into less trouble.

In this specific case, I wouldn't recommend `using` since you expect to use the font object outside the `AssignFont` method.

So, when do you dispose the font? One way is, you could dispose the font on the `Disposed` event of the parent control (assuming `this` is a control). However, *unless* you have thousands of fonts being generated during your application lifetime, you most like *don't* have to dispose the font at all. If you just have 5-10 fonts in the app, disposing them shouldn't be a big point of concern.